# How to set a random ID on a sqlite Prisma Database?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, prisma

At the moment, my NextJS Website uses Prisma's autoincrement in order to set the IDs on the model "items":

```
model Item {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  link          String
}
```

But I need to change this to make my site a bit more secure. I want the ID's to be random integers between 0 and 99999999999999 (No autoincrement).
Is there an easy way to do that, or do I have to manually generate an ID and check whether that ID already exists?
Greetings, PixelPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a sequence of IDs, I'd suggest to go with something like UUIDs:

```
id   String @id @default(uuid())
```